# python: how-to do a periodic non-blocking lookup

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonblocking, python-asyncio, periodic-task

Could you please advise on how to periodically
execute a task that it takes more time to execute than the periodic interval ?

For example:

```
def lookup():
    # do some lookups, retrieve info, let's assume it takes 60sec to complete
    msg = {'abc':123}
    time.sleep(60)
    return msg

class Publisher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._TIMEIT = 0
        self._INTERVAL = 5
        self._counter = 0

    def xxx():
        t_start = time.time()
        msg = lookup()
        # do something with the value returned
        save_msg_to_db(msg)
        self._counter += 1
        t_end = time.time()
        self._TIMEIT = int(math.ceil(t_end - t_start))

    def run():
        while True:
            # let's do the lookup every 5sec, but remember that lookup takes 60sec to complete
            time.sleep(self._INTERVAL)
            # the call to xxx() should be non-blocking
            xxx()
```

But the `run` method is responsible for scheduling the periodic task,
and as it iterates it should not block when calling the function `xxx`.

I am thinking to create an event loop on every call to `xxx` function, as described in  [A Bad Coroutine Example](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/26/python-3-an-intro-to-asyncio/) but how to do the call to `xxx` non-blocking ?

PS. I am using Python3.4 new to asyncio (was using gevent in the past), not sure if I am asking sth stupid here.

So `lookup` will create a async loop that will take let's say 60sec to complete. But, in the `run` method there is a endless loop running that i would like it to do the lookup every 5sec, in other words I would like to (1) how often i call the lookup function, **independent of** (2) how long it takes lookup to complete

Comment: Is your `lookup()` function CPU-intensive or it just takes long time to complete due to I/O operations?

Comment: : "it just takes long time to complete due to I/O operations"

Comment: And what happens while the `lookup()` is running? If you want to run it in the background (non-blocking) and it takes 60 seconds to complete and you call it every 5 seconds pretty soon you will have thousands of them running. So something has got to give - either your checking interval (extending it) or the calls to the `lookup()` function (don't make another call if the previous didn't complete).

Comment: @zwer well i am counting on the fact that there will 60/5=12 tasks more or less all the time and i am perfectly fine with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `lookup()` is primarily I/O intensive, you can run your `xxx()` method as a thread and be perfectly fine (code shortened for brevity):

```
import threading
import time

class Publisher(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._INTERVAL = 5
        self._counter = 0
        self._mutex = threading.Lock()

    def xxx(self):
        msg = lookup()
        save_msg_to_db(msg)
        with self._mutex:  # make sure only one thread is modifying counter at a given time
            self._counter += 1

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(self._INTERVAL)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.xxx)
            t.setDaemon(True)  # so we don't need to track/join threads
            t.start()  # start the thread, this is non-blocking
```

Comment: thanks @zwer let me evaluate it, and will come back to you